# Which Demon Spoke?

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

While wandering, you encounter a pond, in which two demons are bathing. One is labelled 'honest', meaning they always tell the truth, and the other is labelled 'liar', which means they always lie. As you turn around and leave, you hear a demon's voice say "We aren't labelled correctly". Which of the demons said this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It must be

> the demon labelled "liar".

There are two options:

- > If they **are** labelled correctly, then the one who spoke is a liar *and* labelled as a liar.
- > If they **aren't** labelled correctly, then the one who spoke is honest *but* labelled as a liar.

Note that the puzzle is not entirely well-posed, since it assumes that the only options are that either *both* or *neither* are labelled correctly, i.e. it precludes the possibility of both being honest or both being liars. There is a slight ambiguity in the English phrase "We aren't labelled correctly" - does it mean that they're both labelled incorrectly, or just that they're not both labelled correctly? - and the puzzle exists in this ambiguity.

Comment: What if they are actually both honest?

Comment: @Steve There's an implicit assumption in the puzzle, which should really have been made explicit but wasn't. I've added a paragraph to explain this. I did think about it while solving the puzzle, but not making that assumption would mean it isn't solvable.

Comment: The argument in point 2 doesn't work, under the assumption that "we aren't labelled correctly" means that at least one of them is labelled incorrectly. If they aren't labelled correctly, then one of them is labelled incorrectly. Although the one who spoke is honest, one cannot say that this one is the one who is labelled incorrectly. In fact, it's totally fine that both are honest, and any of them can say that sentence.

Comment: @WhatsUp See the final paragraph of the answer. The puzzle is slightly ill-posed in that it assumes there are only two options, both labelled correctly or neither labelled correctly. (Otherwise, it's unsolvable.)

Comment: Nowhere in the statement of the question says that there are only two options as you stated, so I assume this is your own interpretation. In fact I totally agree that the puzzle is ill-posed. My point is, if you think a puzzle is ill-posed, then should you still post an answer to it?

Comment: @WhatsUp I'm answering the puzzle *as intended*, and have edited to point out the ill-posedness for completeness. Not all puzzlers are as pedantic as they perhaps should be :-)

Comment: Well, it seems to me that you are answering the puzzle as *you* intend it to be. What I would expect is to vote for close or to ask OP for more clarification (which sadly doesn't gain you rep, then).

Comment: @WhatsUp More like, answering the puzzle as it's *clearly* intended to be, the only parsing of it which makes sense as a solvable puzzle. It sometimes happens like this with logic puzzles, when they're not worded precisely enough for true logicians but the way it's meant to be read and solved is clear, or at least clear to people experienced with this type of puzzle.

Comment: Suggested edit- Note: after solving the puzzle, add a sentence making it more explicit, we still don't know if the demon who spoke is actually a liar or honest.

Answer (score 2):

The demon labelled "Liar" because he's actually honest who's labelled as liar. So he must be the one who said it and he's right, in one case.

In another case, it becomes a vicious circle. If the honest one said and we believed , so he's trying to say in real he's actually a liar . It means he can't be believed and they're labelled correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This question was already answered. Yet, I thought to give my answer without seeing the solutions.

> Both of them could have said that.

Because

> **Honest** under the label liar is telling the truth

Or,

> **Liar** under the correct label is trying to deceive you.